# How to use scrapy to crawl multi level pages? (two level)

Tags: scrapy

On the first page it well scraping the text "test1" in title tag but nothing in page two "test2.html"
my script:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider

from scrapy.selector import Selector

from testscrapy1.items import Website

class DmozSpider(Spider):

     name = "bill"
     allowed_domains = ["http://www.mywebsite.com"]
     start_urls = [
         "http://www.mywebsite.com/test.html"]



def parse(self,response):

    for site in response.xpath('//head'):
        item = Website()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        yield item

    yield scrapy.Request(url="www.mywebsite.com/test1.html", callback=self.other_function)

def other_function(self,response):

    for other_thing in response.xpath('//head'):
        item = Website()
        item['title'] = other_thing.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Thank you in advance STEF

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use scrapy to crawl multiple pages? (two level)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954423/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-multiple-pages-two-level)

Comment: `scrapy.Request(url="www.mywebsite.com/test1.html", callback=self.other_function)` seem odd. Shouldn't you rather set `url` to something dynamic like `urlparse.urljoin('www.mywebsite.com', site.url)` (no working code, just some example)? `Request` tells scrapy which sites to visit next. If you make this a fixed string, it will scrape the same site multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Try

yield scrapy.Request(url="www.mywebsite.com", callback=self.other_function)

instead of

yield scrapy.Request(url="www.mywebsite.com/test1.html", callback=self.other_function)